# How diagnostics frame will reach to DM( Diagnostics Management) in adaptive autosar

Tags: diagnostics, autosar

There are four layers in Adaptive AutoSAR.

> - Application
> - ARA
> - AP foundation and AP Services
> - Hardware/Machine/Virtual Machine
>
>   Once diagnostics frame is received on hardware, how it will be processed and will reach to Diagnostics Management?
>
>   As in classic platform, there was Socket adapter and TcpIp stack, to create socket and resolve the source and destination IP and MAC address for received frames, how same will be handled in Adaptive platform.
>
>   In DM specification by AutoSAR, Interface between DM and adaptive application is given(service interface, methods, fields etc) but interface between machine(HW) and DM is not given. Please help me to understand the communication between DM and Machine.

Answer (score 0):

The AUTOSAR spec defines, that DM has an UDS Transport Layer compliant to ISO-13400 (called DoIP), which might later be extended to also connect to other Tp Implementations for CAN, CAN-FD and Flexray.